# Unable to add class on href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add class on href tag when i click upon it.
I'm using .addclass function of jquery but it is not working for me.
here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('addClass').click(function(){
    $('addClass').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<a href="#" id="addClass">clickme</a><br>
<a href="#" id="addClass">clickme</a><br>
<a href="#" id="addClass">clickme</a><br>
<a href="#" id="addClass">clickme</a>
```

Here is my code.
problem is unable to add the class on click the href and also remove the class if somoen href tag already have to.

Comment: $('addClass') should be $('#addClass')

Comment: but if you see so it is not removing old added class to href tag

Comment: Actually it should be $(". addClass") and all the IDs should be class since you cannot have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot have duplicate IDs
2. You had a typo missing the type selector (# in your case but that would not have worked anyway because of 1)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.addClass').click(function() {
    $('.addClass').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active  { background-color:red }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<a href="#" class="addClass">clickme</a><br>
<a href="#" class="addClass">clickme</a><br>
<a href="#" class="addClass">clickme</a><br>
<a href="#" class="addClass">clickme</a>
```